# If $\cos x = \frac35$ and $x$ lies between $\pi$ and $2\pi$, find the value of $\tan x$

Tags: trigonometry

I have used the Pythagorean identity to show that $\tan x = \frac43$.
Then I used the unit circle to see that the angle lies in the third and/or fourth quadrant because they are between $\pi$ and $2\pi$.  This means that tan in those quadrants is either positive (in the third quadrant) or negative (in the fourth quadrant).
So my answer was $\tan x = \pm\frac43$.

However the answer is negative 4/3.  (Not positive 4/3).

I am wondering where I am going wrong.
Does the question mean that there is only one answer ie: with one sign?
Can there be two answers to the question like I have obtained?
If there is only one answer then which one do I pick since both lie in the stated range of $\pi$ to $2\pi$?
Thanks a lot.  I thought I was ready to start calculus, but it looks like I'm back to the drawing board.

On a side note I have a profile in this site but don't know how to ask a question using my profile so I am posting this question as a guest.  Can someone advise me how to post a question using my profile?

Comment: The cosine is positive, and we are between $\pi$ and $2\pi$. So we are between $3\pi/2$ and $2\pi$ (fourth quadrant). And in the fourth quadrant tan is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pythagorean identity implies, as you know, that $tan^2(x) = \frac{16}{9}$. Look at the unit circle again. If $cos(x) = \frac{3}{5} > 0$ then x must lie in the fourth quadrant. Thus $cos(x) > 0$ and $sin(x) < 0$. Since $tan(x) = \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}$, then $tan(x) < 0$ (since a negative divided by a positive is negative). Thus we must take the negative square root of $\frac{16}{9}$ as our solution, i.e. $tan(x) = -\sqrt{\frac{16}{9}} = -\frac{4}{3}$. As we can see, this is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be negative as $x$ lies in the 4th quadrant and in that quadrant tan is negative hence. It should be $-4/3$.

Answer (score 0):

You have done almost everything correctly. What you have missed is that for any angle lying in  third quadrant cosine of that angle is negative. Hence the angle 'x' can not lie in the third quadrant because cos(x) is 3/5 which is positive. Thus angle 'x' can lie only in fourth quadrant. Hence tan(x) can only be -4/3